# Producing cherenkov radiation using radioactive source

Tags: radioactivity, cherenkov-radiation

I want to produce cherenkov radiation by transpering $\beta$ particles through a dialectric media. To do this , I will use a radioactive decay as a source for the  $\beta$  particles, The thing that bother me is that the radiation (the visible spectrum) will be too faint. My question is
:

How can I relate between my radioactive source and the brightness of the radiation (the visible spectrum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Frank-Tamm formula, which describes the energy emitted ($E$) per unit frequency ($\omega$) per unit length ($x$):
$$ \frac{\partial^2E}{\partial x\,\partial \omega}=
\frac{q^2}{4\pi}\mu(\omega)\omega\Big[1-
\frac{c^2}{v^2n^2({\omega})}
\Big],$$
where $\mu(\omega)$ and $n(\omega)$ are the frequency dependent permeability and index of refraction, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, what is a typical values for none faint light?